# Find the parent of the searched value using javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a JSON data in the following format which needs to be filtered based on a specific value :

```
[
{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "ROOT-0",
    "childs": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "ROOT-1",
            "childs": [
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "name": "ROOT-11",
                },
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "name": "ROOT-12",
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "ROOT-2",
            "childs": [
                {
                    "id": 21,
                    "name": "ROOT-21",
                },
                {
                    "id": 22,
                    "name": "ROOT-22",
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "ROOT-3",
            "childs": [
                {
                    "id": 31,
                    "name": "ROOT-31",
                },
                {
                    "id": 32,
                    "name": "ROOT-32",
                },

            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

The scenario is that I need to get **ROOT-1** as final result if I look for **ROOT-11/ROOT-12**.

I have tried filtering with this following code

`var res = data[0].filter(function f(o) {
  if (o.name.includes("ROOT-11")) return o;
})`

But I am not able to get a grip on the logic. Is there a way to achieve my desired output

Comment: how deep is your array/object?

Comment: Not entirely clear what expected results are. You just want the name value returned?

Comment: @NinaScholz Max depth is 3

Comment: @charlietfl Yes charlie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `find()`...

```
var result = data[0].childs.find(x => {
    return x.childs.find(y => {
        return y.name === name;
    });
}).name;
```

Or you could write a function...

```
function findParentName(name, data) {
    return data[0].childs.find(x => {
        return x.childs.find(y => {
            return y.name === name;
        });
    }).name;
}

var result = findParentName('ROOT-11', data);

console.log(result);
```

Doing this will give you the best performance result as `find()` will return as soon as it finds a match, and not iterate through each remaining loop like `forEach()` or `map()`

If you're using ES6 you can say...

```
const result = data[0].childs.find(x => x.childs.find(y => y.name === 'ROOT-11')).name;
```

Comment: what happens if the wanted name is in the possibly second object of the array?

Comment: You could easily iterate through an array at a top level, but my answer is aiming to solve the problem with the given data array not a theoretical array with more indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You could, *for an arbitrary count nested children*, use a **recusion approach** by iterating the actual level and if not found check the children with the actual name.

If the wanted name is found, the parent's name is handed over through all nested calls and returned.

```js
function getParent(array, search, parent) {
    return array.some(o => o.name === search || o.children && (parent = getParent(o.children, search, o.name)))
        && parent;
}

var data = [{ id: 0, name: "ROOT-0", children: [{ id: 1, name: "ROOT-1", children: [{ id: 11, name: "ROOT-11" }, { id: 12, name: "ROOT-12" }] }, { id: 2, name: "ROOT-2", children: [{ id: 21, name: "ROOT-21" }, { id: 22, name: "ROOT-22" }] }, { id: 3, name: "ROOT-3", children: [{ id: 31, name: "ROOT-31" }, { id: 32, name: "ROOT-32" }] }] }]


console.log(getParent(data, 'ROOT-0'));  // undefined no parent found
console.log(getParent(data, 'ROOT-1'));  // ROOT-0
console.log(getParent(data, 'ROOT-11')); // ROOT-1
console.log(getParent(data, 'ROOT-31')); // ROOT-3
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the item using a few filters and a find, to get the result you are looking for:

```js
let items = [{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "ROOT-0",
  "childs": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "ROOT-1",
      "childs": [{
          "id": 11,
          "name": "ROOT-11",
        },
        {
          "id": 12,
          "name": "ROOT-12",
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "ROOT-2",
      "childs": [{
          "id": 21,
          "name": "ROOT-21",
        },
        {
          "id": 22,
          "name": "ROOT-22",
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "ROOT-3",
      "childs": [{
          "id": 31,
          "name": "ROOT-31",
        },
        {
          "id": 32,
          "name": "ROOT-32",
        },

      ]
    }
  ]
}]

function find(name) {
  let result
  items.filter(item =>
    result = item.childs.find(item2 =>
      item2.childs.filter(i => i.name == name).length > 0
    )
  )
  return result.name || ''
}

console.log(find('ROOT-11'))
console.log(find('ROOT-22'))
console.log(find('ROOT-32'))
```